# Creating an array of buttons

Tags: arrays, qt, button, minesweeper

I am more or less a complete beginner, so please excuse me if that Question does come across as too easy, but I try to create in QT an Array of Bottons. It should look similarly to the Minesweeper Game. Is there another way than to create every single butto or even have, when the program is running, the user choose how big the Array is, for example an 8x8 field.
My Goal is in the end that the user can make somewhat like a map where he can Color each button in the Array differently, but it would be really helpful if someone could tell me just how to create the Array. If possible in Detail, because I am not that used to work with QT or C++.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested QVector instead of arrays to save your buttons, and here is a peace of code which creates 8*8 buttons view on Qt MainWindow and saves the buttons in QVector, it may help

```
QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout();
ui->centralwidget->setLayout(layout);

QVector<QVector<QPushButton*>> buttons2DVector(8);

for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
    buttons2DVector[i].resize(8);

    for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
        QPushButton *b = new QPushButton("button");
        layout->addWidget(b,i,j);
        buttons2DVector[i][j] = b;
    }
}
```

Then you can easily access any of your buttons using

```
  buttons2DVector[rowNum][columnNum]->func();
```

Comment: Where do I put the Code in? Sry I really am a beginner.

Comment: Create a QT Widget Application project, you should found a class created by default called "MainWindow", put this code in its constructor.
this may be useful as a clarification for the idea,but you should adjust it to fulfill your needs.

Comment: SO thats the Code in my mainwindow.cpp:

 `
 #include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
 `

Sry but I dont know what the class and what the constructor here is..